# Draw links to a d3 circle pack layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to be able to draw links between the circles in a circle pack layout, like `{source: i, target: j}`. I've seen some questions about how to combine this layout with the force layout that made me think It could be a way to achieve this but I haven't had any luck on that path, also what I need is something completely static. Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

I finally could draw lines between nodes by appending them to the svg and calculating each line position based on the radius of the nodes that each line were to connect, but the problem was that the pack layout that I'm using is zoomable, so when I tried to zoom by clicking the lines neither translate nor re-sized (of course, since there was no code performing such things), so I tried to implement a translation function for the lines so they would move along with the zoom, then I saw that it would take some serious geometry to achieve this, so since I'm a lazy programmer and not at all experienced with d3 I tried to come with something more simple... at last I decided to represent the links between the nodes with a different approach (without lines), I used the "mouseover" event so when the pointer is over a node it will highlight (changed circle stroke attribute color and width) the nodes connected to it. This way I achieved my goal and the view looks a lot cleaner without all the lines crossing over it (they were a lot). I know that some may think that this does not answer the original question, and I'm sure that this can be achieved by someone with more experience (and time and patience) using lines and implementing the right calculation, but in my case this solution solves my problem and maybe it could be of help to others.